# JQuery Filter Tag Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a clicked "a class mail" href value in order to filter it and add a one word string after the text "...subject=[Site]..." to be like this: "...subject=[Site] string..."

envie um e-mail para sites@atipico.com.br

This is as far as I can go:

`$('a.mail').click(function(event){
$(this).prop('href',$(this).prop('href').replace('[Curso]', '[Curso] some text'));
});`

I replaced prop by attr but it did not work...

`$('a.mail').click(function(event){
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('[Curso]', '[Curso] some text'));
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would like to invite you to write code as readable as you can. Here's how I would do what you're trying to achieve:

```
$('a.mail').click(function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var linkUrl = $this.attr('href');

    linkUrl = linkUrl.replace('[Curso]', '[Curso] some text');
    $this.attr('href', linkUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr()` instead of `prop()` as these are different things.